# Apache Camel splitter with hazelcast seda queue

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to do a file import process where a file is picked up in a subdirectory of a given folder, the subdirectory identifying the client the file is for, then the records are parsed, split, and sent on Hazelcast SEDA queues. I want to process each record as its read off of the Hazelcast SEDA queue, then it returns a status code (created, updated, or errored) which can be aggregated.

I'm also creating a job record when the file is first picked up and I want to update the job record with the final count of created, updated, and errors.

The JobProcessor below creates this record and sets the client Organization and Job objects in headers on the message. The CensusExcelDataFormat reads an Excel file and creates an Employee object for each line, then returns a Collection.

```
from("file:" + censusDirectory + "?recursive=true").idempotentConsumer(new SimpleExpression("file:name"), idempotentRepository)
      .process(new JobProcessor(organizationService, jobService, Job.JobType.CENSUS))
      .unmarshal(censusExcelDataFormat)
      .split(body(),  new ListAggregationStrategy()).parallelProcessing()
      .to(ExchangePattern.InOut, "hazelcast:seda:process-employee-import").end()
      .process(new JobCompletionProcessor(jobService))
.end();

from("hazelcast:seda:process-employee-import")
      .idempotentConsumer(simple("${body.entityId}"), idempotentRepository)
      .bean(employeeImporterJob, "importOrUpdate");
```

The problem I'm having is that the list aggregation happens immediately and instead of getting a list of statuses I'm getting the same list of Employee objects. I want the Employee objects to be sent on the SEDA queue and the return value from the processing on the queue to be aggregated then run through the JobCompletionProcessor to update the Job record.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is you are seeing is the default behavior. The apache camel [splitter documentation](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) clearly states this in the what the splitter returns section.

1. **Camel 2.2 or older:** The Splitter will by default return the last
   splitted message.
2. **Camel 2.3 and newer:** The Splitter will by default return the
   original input message.
3. **For all versions:** You can override this by supplying your own
   strategy as an AggregationStrategy. There is a sample on this page
   (Split aggregate request/reply sample). Notice it's the same
   strategy as the Aggregator supports. This Splitter can be viewed as
   having a build in light weight Aggregator.

So as you can see you are required to implement your own splitter aggregation strategy. To do this create a new class that implements AggrgationStrategy something like the code below:

```
public class MyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy 
{
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
      if (oldExchange == null) //this would be null on the first exchange.
      {
           //do some work on the first time if needed
      }
      /*
         Here you put your code to calculate failed, updated, created. 


      */
    }
}
```

You can then use your custom aggregation strategy by specifying it like the following examples:

```
.split(body(), new MyAggregationStrategy()) //Java DSL
<split strategyRef="myAggregationStrategy"/> //XML Blueprint
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the splitter. I implemented this without the Hazelcast SEDA queues to just run locally and this is working:

Comment: `from("file:" + censusDirectory + "?recursive=true").idempotentConsumer(new SimpleExpression("file:name"), idempotentRepository)
          .process(new JobPreProcessor(organizationService, jobService, Job.JobType.CENSUS))
          .unmarshal(censusExcelDataFormat)
          .split(body(), new ListAggregationStrategy())
          .parallelProcessing()
          .bean(employeeImporterJob, "processItem")
          .end()
          .bean(new JobCompletion(jobService), "completeJob")
          .end();`